# Position element center of background Image

Tags: html, css

I've a picture that I putted it background of my web page.

```
body
{
    background-image: url('../Image/Background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
```

I have a DIV that I want to put it center of the background Image.
Should I set padding left and top to 50% ?

Comment: is the div fixed width or is it dynamic?

Comment: Its fix width with this content for example : 
Hello, this is a test

Comment: Ah, ok. Then see my post.  That should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
        background-color: blue; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        .div {
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            text-align:center;
            height: 100px;
            top: 100px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class ="div">
        <p>ahgdsgdhuagh</p>
        <p>ahgdsgdhuagh</p>
        <p>ahgdsgdhuagh</p>
        <p>ahgdsgdhuagh</p>
        <p>ahgdsgdhuagh</p>
        <p>ahgdsgdhuagh</p>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

This sould do the trick.

Comment: I want position DIV center of background image

Comment: ok, then my answer should do the trick. in my answer you dont have to specify the width and height, because they are set to 100%. If you want to specify width and height you should use Joseph answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's fixed width (say 500px by 300px) Then you can do something like this:

```
#myDiv
{
    position:fixed;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-250px; /*half the width*/
    margin-top:-150px; /*half the height*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you. what should I exactly set for width property ?

Comment: whatever looks good I would say.  Or if it is just text in the div, you could set a large value and set its `text-align` css property to `center`;